# Getting a lot of extra error information ".../commands/console.rb:..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb, rails-console

I'm working on a ruby on rails tutorial and using the rails console

When an error occurs I'm seeing a lot more error information than the tutorial shows (could be that they ommited it for brevity)

For example:

```
2.1.1 :001 > asdf
NameError: undefined local variable or method `asdf' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2.1.1 :002 >
```

Whereas the tutorial would only show:

```
2.1.1 :001 > asdf
NameError: undefined local variable or method `asdf' for main:Object
```

Is that other information useful? Is there a way to suppress it?

Comment: they did omit it for brevity.

Comment: Thanks ok; didn't thought to look in those actual files to see what's there (may not get to it...) :)